# Retrieving Latest Object Version from s3a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs, hadoop2

Is there any way to get the latest object version from an s3 versioning enabled bucket, using s3a connector, with the help of hadoop cli?

Comment: I think that you just access the object as normal. It would always return the "current" (latest) version.

Comment: But how to confirm the accessed object the the latest one. I am not able to see the version id suffixed with it. Is there any way to get the specified version/all the versions using hadoop cli?

Comment: If you request an object without specifying the VersionId, then the latest version will always be returned. I'm not sure how to specify a particular version via the Hadoop CLI. Hopefully somebody else will be able to comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Is there any way to get all the versions of a particular object in Spark/Scala?

Comment: If you use an AWS SDK you can access specific versions. I'm not sure about other interfaces used by Spark/Scala though.

Answer (score 2):

If you download and build hadoop trunk (i.e the latest) then you can in your own code list call `fs.getFileStatus(filepath)` (where FS is the filesystem from FileSystem.get() on an s3a path), and then log that you'll see the values: we now include it and the etag in the S3AFileStatus class and its `toString()` will print it.

In Hadoop 3.1 + you can get the etag value from fs.getFileChecksum, provided your app configuration set "fs.s3a.etag.checksum.enabled" to true (long story). That's in HDP-3.0 and probably CDH 6.2 too. No version there, but if you know the etag you can check.

As to whether its "the latest", remember we get eventually consistent listings: we list what s3 gives us, and if you overwrite a file with a newer version, we may get either back on a listing. What the versioning does do is ensure that on overwrites/deletes you can still get the old one to recover (AWS tooling) and for S3A in future Hadoop version, that we can defend against someone updating a file while you are reading it -you'll always get the version you started with, even if it has been overwritten